# Help with transformations

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, data-transformation, gamma-distribution

I am working with these transformations and I'm not sure why I can't solve this problem. It's pretty easy but my math isn't working out...I may fundamentally misunderstand something.

$X1, X2, X3$ are distributed   $Gamma(\alpha,\beta)$

define $U_1=X_1+X_2$, $U_2=X_2/{(X_1 + X_2)}$, $U_3=X_3/(X_1 + X_2 + X_3)$

show one can express $$x_1=u_1(1-u_2)(1-u_3), x_2=u_1u_2(1-u_3), x=u_1u_3$$

---

Like I said, I thought this was pretty basic. $x_3$ is the most basic, so I'll write out what I did for that. I just went...

$$x_3=u_1u_3=(x_1+x_2)(x_3)/(x_1+x_2+x_3)=$$

$$x_1x_3/(x_1+x_2+x_3)+x_2x_3/(x_1+x_2+x_3)$$

but then I got stuck. I think I'm misunderstanding something. Does it deal with the fact that the variables are capitalized when defined and lower case in the question?

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the problem statement. Take all $X$'s to equal 1. Then $U_1=2$, $U_2=1/2$ and $U_3=1/3$. The formulas imply $X_3=U_1U_3$ or $1=2/3$.

Comment: Somebody made a typographical error.  Let $U_1 = X_1+X_2+X_3$.